# ASP.NET Core with React.js Template targeting .NET 6 - Trouble accessing wwwroot files when scaffolding Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-spa

I'm currently having troubles with how the new template for 'ASP.NET Core with React.js' using .NET 6 as the target framework accesses the wwwroot folder when using individual account authentication, and scaffolding the Identity pages down.

[ASP.NET Core with React.js template in VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBg56.png)

From what I see, when you first create the project using individual account authentication, the wwwroot folder is not created until you scaffold at least one thing from Identity. When you do scaffold that first item, the wwwroot folder appears in the application root.

[from https://github.com/berhir/AspNetCore.SpaYarp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjZqM.png)

When editing something like the 'site.js' file, those changes don't appear in the 'site.js' file that is rendered when visiting one of the identity pages:
[Unedited site.js in client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e98G.png)

I have existing razor pages for account back-end stuff that I'd like to carry over to this specific template, but am stuck due to not being able to pass new js libs within the base wwwroot folder to these Identity pages.

Any help on solutions on how to add new items to the wwwroot folder, and access them within the Identity pages would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Kakarot91, `the wwwroot folder is not created until you scaffold at least one thing from Identity`, yes the wwwroot does not contain in react project by default, but you said it will be generated after scaffolding Identity?